# Computing the average value of a function with a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the integral $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1} f(x,y) dxdy$$

Compute the average value of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+x^3}$ on the region R

The average value of a function is $\frac{1}{A}\iint f(x,y) dxdy$

and $A$ is the area of the region R

In the solution it says that the area of the region is 1 and I'm confused about this. The graph of the region should look like this right?

[image]

So why is the area of this region 1?

As for the rest of the solution, it says this is the answer and I want to verify that this is correct:

Reverse order of integration:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{x^2} \sqrt{1+x^3} dydx$$

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{1+x^3} x^2 dx$$

Let $u=x^3+1$, $du=3x^2dx$

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt{u} du=\frac{2^{5/2}-2}{9}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the area of $R$ is not $1$. It's rather obvious from the picture you've provided that it must be less than $1$, which is the area of the square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. In fact, it's equal to your double integral, replacing $\sqrt{1+x^3}x^2$ with $1$:
$$
A = \int_0^1 \int_0^{x^2} dy\, dx
$$
which, I'm sure you'll have no problem working out, is equal to $\frac 13$.

Comment: im confused, so is the final answer $\frac{1}{3}$ or is it $\frac{1}{1/3}*\frac{2^{5/2}-2}{9}=\frac{2^{5/2}-2}{3}$?

Comment: also, is the region that I graphed correct?

Comment: My answer states that $A = \frac 13$. I believe you already stated that the average value of the function is $\frac 1A \iint f(x, y) dx \, dy$.

Comment: Yes, that region looks correct to me

Comment: Thank you so much! So is the process for calculating $\int \int f(x,y) dxdy$ correct? It switches the bounds of integration and performs a u-sub

Comment: i.e. I get $\frac{2^{5/2}-2}{9}$

Comment: Yes that's correct